# getting google contacts names using oauth

Tags: php, oauth

Currently I'm using a piece of code to get the google contact emails from a google account and display them into a table. The emails show up correctly but I would like the name of the person to show up as well. The code that I am using currently are as follows. I know that the $xml contains the name (I tried printing out on a html) but I do not know how to display it. $result does not contain the names anymore so I'm guessing the name displaying have to to come before that. Does anyone have any idea?

```php
//passing accesstoken to obtain contact details
$xmlresponse =  file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token='.$tok_value.'&max-results=500');
//print_r($xmlresponse);
//reading xml using SimpleXML
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
//print_r($xml);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
//after dumping there is no names in the result
$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');
//var_dump($result);
$count = 0;
echo "<table class=\"inv-table\" cellpadding=\"5\">";
foreach ($result as $title) 
{
    //echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br><br>";
    echo "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" 
                         name=\"email_to[]\" 
                         value=".$title->attributes()->address.">".$title->attributes()->address;
    echo "</td></tr>";
    //echo $title->attributes()->displayName;
    //echo $title->fullName;
    $count = $count + 1;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in the loop:

```
echo $xml->entry[$count]->title;
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above method where `echo $xml->entry[$count]->title;` which did not work as this does not give the correct names to the emails. Instead I did this:

```
// https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?updated-min=1970-03-16T00:00:00&max-results=10000");

function getNamesAndEmails ($xml_response) {
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml_response);
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

    $results = array ();
    foreach($xml->entry as $entry){

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($entry->asXML());

        $ary = array ();
        $ary['name'] = (string) $entry->title;

        foreach ($xml->email as $e) {
          $ary['emailAddress'][] = (string) $e['address'];
        }

        if (isset($ary['emailAddress'][0])) {
            $ary['email'] = $ary['emailAddress'][0];
        }

        $results[] = $ary;

    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to get the names. I've been trying to deal with the same problem.

I noticed you tried to `echo $title->fullName`, it won't be under `$title` because this is just the results of all the email addresses the were found, which only have and address and some other optional items (none of which is the name).

If you `print_r($xml)` you should see the names there, but for me, no amount of xpath could retrieve them for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a very similar solution but works great to me:

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=2000&oauth_token=$token";
$xmlresponse =  file_get_contents($url);
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');

$contacts = array();
foreach ($result as $key=>$title) {
    $contact = new stdClass();
    $contact->name = sprintf("%s", $xml->entry[$key]->title[0]);
    $contact->email = sprintf("%s", $title->attributes()->address);
    $contacts[] = $contact;
}
```

So, after loop, you have an array with simple object, filled with name and e-mail.